# Insertion to MongoDB in Docker is very slow

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.4"

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "6433:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

After I run it with `docker compose up`, I am trying to upload a document into it:
`mongosh localhost:6433 -u username -p password < data.js`
The document is a simple json like that, and "big_value_key"'s value size is about 3.5 Mb, and other values are tiny:

```
    "key_1": "value",   
    "key_2": 1,
    "big_value_key": *really big string*,
    ...
    "key_n": 2
})
```

Then it starts printing the document into terminal char by char, and it does it slow. It seems it will take several hours to insert a single 3.5 Mb document.

What am I doing wrong? I want it to be fast.